# how to get query string parameters from network selenium+Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need the Query String Parameters values from the network tab for the Google analytics validations

I have tried with getting the values by enabling Performance logging, But am only getting the Response header, not the Query string parameters

I have tried with Below code but am only getting the response header details, I need the query parameters details from the network tab
My code:

```
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences(); 
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs); 
LogEntries logs = driver.manage().logs().get("performance");
```

[Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu7em.png)

Comment: Ask a question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, edit your question with the additional details instead of posting it as a comment.